# Using latitude and longitude in Javascript but can't get the values - getting an error?

Tags: javascript, function, api, callback, latitude-longitude

I'm using the following code but instead of console.log , I want to use the
user_position.lat and user_position.lng in some other section of my code.

```
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
          var lat_lng = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
           console.log(position);
          var user_position = {};
          user_position.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
          user_position.lng = position.coords.longitude; 
          callback(user_position);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
getLocation(function(lat_lng){
  //console.log(user_position.lat);
});


I want to use the following outside of a function to get the latitude and longitude 
but always getting an error (user_position.lat not defined)

var lat = user_position.lat
var lng = user_postion.lng
```

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: Please update with complete code

Comment: I want to use the lat and long in my response API:

var responseTwo;

responseTwo = getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=xxxxauthtokenxxxx');

        var currentWind = JSON.parse(responseTwo).wind.speed;
        var currentRain = JSON.parse(responseTwo).rain["1h"];
        console.log(JSON.parse(responseTwo));

Comment: No in your question you have a code sample that is incomplete, also it looks like you're using a callback pattern but dont show it fully implemented, this could be a one line fix. Basically user_position is limited by scope right now and you need to get it to the top scope so that it's usable outside of where it's defined.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure since if I just do the console.log in my getLocation function, I see the lat and long shown. I just can't access it out of that scope.
Not sure how to get it to the top scope to be usable outside.
Thank you.

Comment: Please checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonOrchanian "*I want to use the values outside of a function*" - that is impossible. Move the other code that uses them inside the callback, so that it won't get executed before the values are loaded.